# Detect Split Screen mode in windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, mfc

How to detect split screen mode in windows 8. I have a wim32 desktop application(written in MFC) and i need to provide some functionality in case of split screen mode
FYI - In split screen mode both desktop and metro mode come side by side

Comment: Why do you need different functionality if the user has a modern-ui app docked to the side of the screen?  What is it you need to do if that is the case?  Is the issue simply one of resizing your own program, or are you trying to interact with the modern-ui app?

Comment: my app works outside the OS area and i use custom written middleware driver code to communicate with the drivers. I'm using a web browser control to open up content in the OS region. For positioning the web browser I need to take into account the right,bottom coordinated of the screen. In case of split screen, the MFC provided API's do not give the correct co-ordinates of the desktop occupied region; thats my point of trouble. I need to see if the user is operating in split-screen mode and then modify my co-ordinates accordingly

Comment: So it's partly a resizing/positioning issue.  Ok.  Can you provide some code to show what method you are currently using to get the coordinates/dimensions? My guess is you're mixing a combination of Screen, Desktop, Window, and Client coordinates, so if we see what you're doing now we can advise.

Comment: I'm using GetSystemMetrics() with SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN as parameters to get screen height and width. What i want is the co-ordinates of the desktop region only,but what i get are the complete screen co-ordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, the reason you're getting the screen size is because that's what you're asking for.  Passing `SM_CXSCREEN` and `SM_CYSCREEN` to `GetSystemMetrics()` will return, as the name suggests, the width and height of the primary display.

There are a number of solutions, each with their pro's and con's, the simplest of which is probably:

```
RECT rcDesktop;
BOOL ok = GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcDesktop);
```

This will return the size of the desktop window of the primary monitor.  If you wanted just the "useable" area (taking into account the taskbar):

```
RECT rc;
BOOL ok = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &rc, 0);
```

In the case of having a Modern-UI app docked to the side of the screen, both of those should return what you want, depending on whether you want to cover the taskbar with your program or not.

Note that those examples will only return information for the primary monitor on multi-monitor systems.  You can get information about a specific monitor, such as the monitor that your current window is located on, by doing the following:

```
MONITORINFO mon_info;
mon_info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
BOOL ok = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &mon_info);
```

The `MONITORINFO` structure contains the size (and position - don't assume it's 0,0) of the requested monitor, including the work area:

**Caveat**: I'm not at home on my Windows8 system, so I can't check that all of these will return the correct information, but in theory checking the work area *should* do what you want, unless you specifically want your program to be full-screen.

Comment: Hey, thanx a ton. The GetWindowRect gives the same results as GetSystemMetrics but SystemParametersInfo gave me what i wanted. Appreciate your help.